# The em dash, and correct usage in the sentence that follows

Tags: writing-style, em-dashes

As I walked through the channel — I knew it was over. 
Is this a correct usage of the em dash?

Comment: No.  IMO, that sentence requires an ordinary comma.

Comment: That -- is two hyphens. This — is an em dash. There is a [punctuation guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/punctuation) published by The Oxford Dictionaries, part of which is their [Em dash guide](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/dash-and-em-dash).

Comment: Usually an em dash signifies an abrupt or drastic change in the direction of a sentence. I don't think this sentence qualifies.The independent clause,"I knew it was over," seems to flow naturally from the dependent clause. "As I walked through the channel." For example, "As I walked through the channel--hell, it's all a lie. There was no channel."

Comment: No dash and no comma.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can use a dash to connect two clauses that aren't complete sentences, but in this case where the second clause flows naturally from the first one, you would be better served using a comma. Dashes are usually used to indicate a change in tone or direction (often to a facetious or informal one).

> After three weeks on set, the cast was fed up with his direction — or, rather, lack of direction.

---

If you're using a dash instead of a comma because you feel that a comma wouldn't give the second clause enough weight, you'll probably need to change your wording. Something like this could work:

> As I walked through the channel, I realized I had to give up. It was over.